# How is 'Kuronue' spelled in kanji?

Tags: japanese-language, yu-yu-hakusho

The only place outside of fanfiction I've seen the name "Kuronue" is in Yu Yu Hakisho, so I suspect they made it up. How is it spelled in kanji in the original media? Or is it ever spelled out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His name is written 黒鵺（くろぬえ）according to the [Japanese Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B9%BD%E2%98%86%E9%81%8A%E2%98%86%E7%99%BD%E6%9B%B8_%E5%86%A5%E7%95%8C%E6%AD%BB%E9%97%98%E7%AF%87_%E7%82%8E%E3%81%AE%E7%B5%86#.E7.99.BB.E5.A0.B4.E4.BA.BA.E7.89.A9).

His name means "black chimera." The [Japanese chimera](http://jisho.org/words?jap=*%E9%B5%BA*&eng=&dict=edict&tag=&sortorder=relevance) is a mythical creature with a monkey's head, tanuki's body, tiger's limbs, and a snake tail.

If you do a Google search for 「黒鵺」, pretty much everything that comes up is about *Yuu Yuu Hakusho*.